# How to test exceptions in PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I am working with plsql and I have some packages which contains procedures and functions and some of the methods contains exceptions.

I have to write some unit test to test the exceptions in the  methods.

Can you tell me please how can I do this?

Is this possible?

Thank you for your time!

BR,
JOHN

Comment: what do you mean to test the exceptions? Do you want to force the code to crash? If so, just use manually RAISE(your_local_exception); in the code to see how the procedure behaves.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test a exception... just use RAISE(exception) in your procedure and make sure when you run the test, it will hit this raise statment;